# How to access value of variable in Mongo?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, variables

```
var a = "act";
db.s.findOne( {
   BrandId: doc.BrandId, 
   a : {$exists:false} 
} ).a;
```

I try to pass the value of variable "a" to my MongoScript. But it looks it can not be simply used. anyone can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build your query step by step and do not use `.` use `[]` instead

```
var a = 'act';
var query = {BrandId: doc.BrandId};
query[a] = {$exists:false};
db.s.findOne(query)[a];
```

Note:

```
query.act == query['act'].
```

Just some javascript tricks.